# What is database sharding and database clusters? How does these work and how to achieve these?

Tags: database, sharding

I have heard a lot about database sharding and cluster. But I am not able to fully understand these concepts. If I have a lot of data, how sharding and clustering can solve it? Are sharding and clustering same or different?

Answer (score 3):

**Sharding** is to spread the data across several databases with a way to access them that does not have to explicitly refer to the physical location.

**Clustering** usually means to establish a tight bond between several machines, so that services can run on either of the machines and be relocated to a different machine in case one machine has a problem.

Your problem lies in your question: how sharding and clustering can solve **it**.

Concentrate on that “it” and figure out *what exactly* you need to do with these data. Then you will be able to find the proper solution more easily.

Comment: Thanks @laurenz-albe.